# Comparing types boto3 (python)

Tags: python, types, boto3

When I execute this `print(type(boto3.resource("s3")) == type(boto3.resource("s3")))`
I'm getting `False`. Is it possible type() `__eq__` to be overwrite. Does anyone can explain why I'm getting `False`

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to print type of `boto3.resource("s3")`, but it has no `type` so it gives you `false`. for example if you give `type('a')` it will give you string same way `boto3.resource("s3")` is used to connect to aws services. which does not have any `type` according to my knowledge.

Comment: But you can save this in variable so that means should have a type